# PYTHON: How to pass tokenizer with keyword arguments to scikit's CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tokenize, feature-extraction, keyword-argument

I have a custom tokenizer function with some keyword arguments:

```
def tokenizer(text, stem=True, lemmatize=False, char_lower_limit=2, char_upper_limit=30):
    do things...
    return tokens
```

Now, how can I can pass this tokenizer with all its arguments to CountVectorizer? Nothing I tried works; this did not work either:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
args = {"stem": False, "lemmatize": True}
count_vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer(**args), stop_words='english', strip_accents='ascii', min_df=0, max_df=1., vocabulary=None)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `tokenizer` should be a callable or None.

(Is `tokenizer=tokenize(**args)` a typo? Your function name above is `tokenizer`.)

You can try this:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda text: tokenizer(text, **args), stop_words='english', strip_accents='ascii', min_df=0, max_df=1., vocabulary=None)
```